# Minimum requirements from android devices for TensorFlow support?

Tags: android, tensorflow

Running the [example android project](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/android) on a weak android device such as ASUS ZenPad P01Z gives really buggy and slow results. Same happens when I try running my custom model on the same device.

What are the known hardware requirements or known range of devices that wouldn't be able to run TensorFlow effectively and efficiently?

Answer (score 3):

I think that this is a difficult question to answer as it is too vague. Your definition of efficient and effective aren't clear.
The minimum specs as far as I know are a device running API Level >21 (although >=23 recommended).

I have it running a number of devices at a decent inference time but it depends on your definition. You can enter debug mode by pressing your volume key to see why your model is running slow and what your inference time is. I have it running on Nexus 6P, Pixel C tablet and some mid-tier Samsung phones fine.

As these demos are rather simple computations (and not too graphically intensive) then I would suggest looking at devices with decent CPUs.

Comment: Awesome tip about the volume button! The inference on the ASUS is about 5-6 times slower than on a Nexus 5X (usually takes more than 3 seconds as opposed to 500-600ms). This is substantial and worrying about the hope of running any model on the ASUS in any realtime use-case... I am wondering if there are any benchmarks so I can know which devices perform reasonably (lets' say, up to 1-1.5 seconds inference time for the camera demo)

Comment: Not sure about any benchmarks. I'm also in the process of trying custom models (but it sounds like you are ahead of me) but I think you can possibly quantize your graph to increase the performance?